# node postgresql listeners and multiple servers

Tags: node.js, postgresql

How does listening to triggers (postgresql) work with multiple instances of server(node, but overall with any server). Will all instances of servers be notified about trigger, or only one, and if multiply instances is there a way to make it that only one will be notified.

Comment: You can only run one instance of postgres

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST - one istance of databases, but several instances of server connected to this database, like with kubernetes.